# Why does this c++ program cause a system crash?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int nums[20] = { 0 };
  int a[10] = { 0 };

  cout << a << endl;
  cout << nums << endl;

  cout << "How many numbers? (max of 10)" << endl;
  cin >> nums[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < nums[0]; i++)
  {
     cout << "Enter number " << i << endl;
     cin >> a[i];
  }
  // Output the numbers entered
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If this program is run and we enter 255 for how many numbers, and 9 for every single number, it causes it to crash.

Comment: What is the second "it" in "it causes it to crash"?  The whole computer OS, or just your program?

Comment: If you're learning C++ the first thing you need to do is understand what tools are available in the Standard Library. [`std:vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a good place to start when storing array-like data. Use those in preference to fixed-length C-style arrays like you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `nums[0]` as the max bound for the loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < nums[0]; i++)
  {
     cout << "Enter number " << i << endl;
     cin >> a[i];
  }
```

In your case you are doing 255 loops and in each iteration you add the value into `a[i]`.

You declared the array `a` to have a size of 10 elements, but you are trying to add 255 elements.

This is the issue. The size of `a` needs to be the same of the max bound value of the main loop (`nums[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

Its because `int a[10] = { 0 };` and you try to index it past the 10th cell or location 9.
You need to fix your for loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i <  nums[0]; i++)
  {
     cout << "Enter number " << i << endl;
     cin >> a[i];
  }
```

or change the length of your cell in intialization

Answer (score 0):

Why does your program crash? You've only allocated 10 elements for `a`.

---

You tell the user `"(max of 10)"`. The user ignores this and types in `255`. You need to check that the user has listened to your warning before doing anything else.

```
cout << "How many numbers? (max of 10)" << endl;
cin >> nums[0];

// Has the user listened to your warning?
if (nums[0] > 10) {
    cout << "Bad input!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```